# Why db.collection.find().forEach is stopped after the first iteration?

Tags: javascript, shell, foreach

I use Robomongo manager.
Open new shell and tried to execute simple query.

Query:

```
db.users.find().forEach(function(user){
        print(user.profile.phone);
    })
```

Result:

```
+120123456789
TypeError: user.profile is undefined :
@(shell):2:9
DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:477:1
@(shell):1:1
```

Comment: Because the code throws an error.

Comment: I've tried to find about this error but no success. (

Comment: The error means that the property `user.profile` doesn't exist. The structure of your data seems to be different from what you think. First find out which properties `user` has.

Comment: But 'profile' property exists.
Here is a screen that proves it: http://prntscr.com/ez1mok

Comment: I understood. The next user really did not have this property. Sorry and thank you.